# Pegar extensão do arquivo para enviar com anexo

Tags: php, magento

Eu tenho um código que envia anexos, eu salvo ele com nome personalizado para encontrar mais fácil depois no banco de dados e também para fazer um backup mais organizado, mas por esse fato, ele não salva a extensão do arquivo.

Nesta parte do código `$emailattachment = $_POST['email'].$date = date('_d-m-Y H:i:s');` eu gostaria de adicionar um `.$extensao`. Como eu faria para pegar a extensão do arquivo original, apenas a extensão e adicionar ali?

Código enviar Anexos?

```
$_UP['pasta'] = '/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/media/teste/';
$_UP['caminho'] = '/media/teste/';
$_UP['renomeia'] = false;

if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "btnSubmit")){

if(isset($_POST['email'])){
$emailattachment = $_POST['email'].$date = date('_d-m-Y H:i:s');
}
if ($_UP['renomeia'] == true) {
  $nome_final = md5(time()).'.jpg';
} else {
  $nome_final = $emailattachment;   
}
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'], $_UP['pasta'] . $nome_final))
```

**Solução**

```
$_UP['pasta'] = '/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/media/teste/';
$_UP['caminho'] = '/media/teste/';
$_UP['renomeia'] = true;

if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "btnSubmit")){

$path = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];

$extensao = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$emailattachment = $_POST['email'] . $date = date('_d-m-Y_H-i-s') .'.'. $extensao;

if ($_UP['renomeia'] == true) {
  $nome_final = $emailattachment;
}
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'], $_UP['pasta'] . $nome_final)) {

  $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
  $query = "INSERT INTO contato (`nome`,`caminho`) VALUES ('".$nome_final."', '".$_UP['pasta']."')";
  $connection->query($query);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando o seu exemplo:

```
//caminho do anexo
$path = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
//pega a extensao do arquivo
$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Mais detalhes de uma olhada [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php).

Comment: Funcionou, mas eu tive que dar uma editada, algumas coisas não estavam "certas"

Comment: @GustavoSouza Poste seu codigo funcional entao, deve ajudar outros.

Comment: Coloquei ali na minha pergunta, "Solução".